# How to make rootfs to img?

Tags: dd

I have image of rootfs which packed in archive rootfs.tar.gz

rootfs.tar.gz contains:

```
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
media
mnt
opt
proc
python
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
test_PO
tmp
usr
var
```

How to make dd .img file of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this instruction, everything works

https://hostingcontroller.com/english/support/HC-Virtualization-Module/WebHelp/HC-Templates/Xen-Templates/Creating_Disk_Image_for_Root_Filesystem.htm